# Ошибка скомпилированного файла Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

Проблема такова, мой Python скрипт работает без ошибок в среде VS code и в обычном Pythhon, но после компиляции файл на секунду открывается и пропадает. На мгновение можно увидеть ошибку

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
   File "play.py , line 7, in <module>
ModileNotFoundError: No module named 'tkVideoPlayer'
[7052] Failed to execute script 'play.py' due to unhandled exception!`
```

И вот такой простой код

```
from tkinter import *
import os
from tkVideoPlayer import TkinterVideo
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '\hide'
root = Tk()
videoplayer = TkinterVideo(master=root, scaled=True)
videoplayer.load(path + "\Video\\Network.mp4")
videoplayer.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
videoplayer.play()
root.iconphoto(False, PhotoImage(file= path + '\icon.ico'))
root.title('Заголовок')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.mainloop()
```

Исользовался Python 3.10 и  Pyinstaller.
Библиотеки os, tkinter и tkVideoPlayer установленны

Comment: Сторонние библиотеки там вроде как-то хитро надо указывать инсталлеру

Answer (score -1):

Пробуйте внимательно читать ошибку. No module named 'tkVideoPlayer'/. У вас есть модуль tk, но нет tkVideoPlayer. from tkVideoPlayer import TkinterVideo. У vs code есть такая не приятная вещь как auto-import. Когда пользуетесь авто-дополнением внимательно смотрите откуда оно импортирует. Если это сделали вы - пересмотрите документацию об этом методе тк вы импортируете метод из не существующего пакета [image: auto-import]

Comment: pip install tkvideoplayer для from tkVideoPlayer import TkinterVideo . гуглите <имя пакета> pypi. Сразу найдете pip команду для установки пакета

Comment: Тс в конце вопроса пишет, что `библиотеки os, tkinter и tkVideoPlayer установлены`

Comment: Существуют библиотеки, у которых команда pip качает другой пакет. Пример dateutill. Команда качает другую зареганую либу под этим именем а команда для установки pip install python-dateutill. Так же рекомендую проверить выбранный интерпретатор. тк возможно у вас выбрано вирт окружение без этой либы

Comment: Библиотека tkVideoPlayer установленна 'pip install tkVideoPlayer' либо приложение либо сам pyinstaller не читает библиотеку